# Spring mvc + hibernate Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Good morning all.
I'm dealing with it for 3 days without getting a solution, I tried to read other similar questione, but no one helped me.
I have my first Spring mvc hibernate application. When deploying it i got this stack trace.
I'm deploying it on Tomcat 8

```
    ERROR [localhost-startStop-3]: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'illuminazioneService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public it.besmart.dao.IlluminazioneDao it.besmart.service.IlluminazioneServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'illuminazioneDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory it.besmart.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionfactory' defined in class path resource [it/besmart/config/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public it.besmart.dao.IlluminazioneDao it.besmart.service.IlluminazioneServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'illuminazioneDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory it.besmart.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionfactory' defined in class path resource [it/besmart/config/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'illuminazioneDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory it.besmart.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionfactory' defined in class path resource [it/besmart/config/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory it.besmart.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionfactory' defined in class path resource [it/besmart/config/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionfactory' defined in class path resource [it/besmart/config/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 51 more
```

As I can understand there is a problem with bean creation, maybe in HibernateConfiguration.

This is HibernateConfiguration.class

```
package it.besmart.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "it.besmart.config" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:db.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionfactory(){
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"it.besmart.models"});
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    return properties;        
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
   return txManager;
}
}
```

db.properties is in the class path (main/src/resources) and the class is in it.besmart.configuration package and the models in it.besmart.models

Than I have IlluminazioneService

```
package it.besmart.service;

import it.besmart.models.Illuminazione;

import java.util.List;

public interface IlluminazioneService {

List <Illuminazione> showIlluminazione();

    Illuminazione findByIdPostoLuce(int idPostoLuce);

    Illuminazione findByIsLit(int isLit);

    void saveIlluminazione(Illuminazione illuminazione);

    void deleteOccupazioneByIdPostoLuce(int idPostoLuce);

}
```

IlluminazioneDao

```
package it.besmart.dao;

import it.besmart.models.Illuminazione;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public interface IlluminazioneDao {

    List <Illuminazione> showIlluminazione();

    Illuminazione findByIdPostoLuce(int idPostoLuce);

    Illuminazione findByIsLit(int isLit);

    void saveIlluminazione(Illuminazione illuminazione);

    void deleteOccupazioneByIdPostoLuce(int idPostoLuce);

}
```

Illuminazione

```
package it.besmart.models;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

/**
 * Illuminazione generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "illuminazione", catalog = "SMARTPARK")
public class Illuminazione implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer idEvento;
    private int idPostoLuce;
    private Date dateTime;
    private boolean isLit;

    public Illuminazione() {
    }

    public Illuminazione(int idPostoLuce, Date dateTime, boolean isLit) {
        this.idPostoLuce = idPostoLuce;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.isLit = isLit;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_evento", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIdEvento() {
        return this.idEvento;
    }

    public void setIdEvento(Integer idEvento) {
        this.idEvento = idEvento;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_posto_luce", nullable = false)
    public int getIdPostoLuce() {
        return this.idPostoLuce;
    }

    public void setIdPostoLuce(int idPostoLuce) {
        this.idPostoLuce = idPostoLuce;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_time", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getDateTime() {
        return this.dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "isLit", nullable = false)
    public boolean isIsLit() {
        return this.isLit;
    }

    public void setIsLit(boolean isLit) {
        this.isLit = isLit;
    }

}
```

AbstractDao is

```
package it.besmart.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao(){
        this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getByKey(PK key) {
        return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
    }

    public void persist(T entity) {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        getSession().delete(entity);
    }

    protected Criteria createEntityCriteria(){
        return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
    }

}
```

I don't know if anything else could be useful for a solution. I have also the implementation classes, if needed.
Thanks to all

EDIT

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.besmart</groupId>
    <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>webapp</name>
    <url>http://www.beingsmart.it</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springframework.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.0.3.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.37</mysql.connector.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <organization>
        <name>Be Smart</name>
        <url>http://www.beingsmart.it</url>
    </organization>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>webapp</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>webapp</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

And last, the IlluminzioneDaoImpl class

```
package it.besmart.dao;

import it.besmart.models.Illuminazione;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("illuminazioneDao")
public class IlluminazioneDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, Illuminazione> implements IlluminazioneDao{

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Illuminazione> showIlluminazione() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
        return (List <Illuminazione>) criteria.list();

    }

    public Illuminazione findByIdPostoLuce(int idPostoLuce) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getByKey(idPostoLuce);
    }

    public Illuminazione findByIsLit(int isLit) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getByKey(isLit);
    }

    public void saveIlluminazione(Illuminazione illuminazione) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        persist(illuminazione);

    }

    public void deleteOccupazioneByIdPostoLuce(int idPostoLuce) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("delete from illuminazione where idPostoLuce = :idPostoLuce"); 
        query.setParameter("idPostoLuce", idPostoLuce);
        query.executeUpdate();

    }   
}
```

Comment: what hibernate version and what spring-version do you use?

Comment: Hibernate versione is 5.0.3.Final and Spring is 4.2.3.Release

Comment: do you use a dependency-management tool (gradle/maven/...) can you post your dependency-configuration? otherwise can you post your classpath?

Comment: Sure, I'm using maven, i'll edit the question with the POM

Comment: Please add the concrete DAO implementation.

Comment: Furthermore, I suggest you to look at spring data to implement your persistence.

Comment: I have added the pom and the implementation of the dao

Comment: I think it's best to set a breakpoint at `SessionFactoryImpl.java:278` and see what `Integrator`s you have and which of them is responsible for the `AbstractMethodError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LocalSessionFactoryBean is a spring-class, dedicated to work with hibernate 4. The *AbstractMethodError* leads to the conclusion that the method/constructor the spring-class is trying to call does not exist on the hibernate-class you have on the classpath. Could it be that you have different versions of hibernate-jars in your classpath?

i would step into the source code of the classes involved. i guess you will find a method-call in *SessionFactoryImpl* to a method/constructor that does not exist for the class-version you have on the classpath. it could be an unsupported ehcache-version or envers-version perhaps.

---

it seems the error has something todo with an incompatible integrator, does that ring a bell?

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.0.CR3/org/hibernate/internal/SessionFactoryImpl.java#SessionFactoryImpl

Answer (score 0):

Spring tries to set the `sessionFactory` on the abstract class `AbstractDao`, and this can not work as the error message notices.

Do you have an `@Component` annotation on the concrete DAO?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with **failed Context initialization**. I am currently with **Spring 5.1.0.Final**. It is logical to use and the latest version of hibernate-validator, but it turned out that the error appears when you put newer than **hibernate-validator 4.3.2.Final**. I can not explain it, but it helped me. Maybe you should try with **lower hibernate-validator version**.

I hope I've been helpful.